# YII2 How to disable widget from calling boostrap.js

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I have in the `AppAsset.php` file the following...

```
public $js = [
    'template/js/bootstrap.js',
];

public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

It is working properly but when I call the [kartik gridview](http://demos.krajee.com/grid), it automatically calls another `bootstrap.js` file so there are two bootstrap in the document that causes bootstrap modal to disappear instantly after showing.

How to prevent the widget from calling the bootstrap.js so? Do i need to just comment the above code and register `bootstrap.js` to every views that needs it?

Answer (score 0):

The given code add bootstrap css as well as js.

```
public $depends = [
 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];
```

So no need to add below

```
public $js = [
'template/js/bootstrap.js',
```

];

Comment: If i remove `template/js/bootstrap.js'` bootstrap.js is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the soution

```
public $js = [

];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];
```